# scanf two integer inputs, break when first input is a certain number and enter is pressed?

Tags: c, for-loop

Apologies at the beginning as I am new to C.

I am using `scanf` to input two integer variables separated by a single space. The `scanf` is inside a `for-loop` but I want to terminate the `for-loop` if the first input is something like `-1`. Here is my code

```
int x,a,b;
for(a=0;a!=-1;)
{
    printf("enter two numbers: \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
}
printf("Program has ended");
```

the outputs should look something like

`enter two numbers:`

`1 5
 2 8
 7 9
-1`

`Program has ended`

Comment: @xing `fgets` are out of the boundary of the course I am doing this for unfortunately :( I will get a zero for the assignment if I use fgets

Comment: @xing unfortunately no :( sorry

Comment: @xing if I were allowed to use `"%[\n]"`, how would I go about?

Comment: @xing the problem with that is the outputs should look exactly the way written below. So outputs for `a` and `b` should have only a space between them and the program exits when only `a` is entered and it is `-1`. My CS teacher just likes making life hard for us :( sorry

Comment: you may need to look more carefully at your requirements. What if the user enters an alphabetical character for the first input? Should the program exit, or should the user be prompted to enter again? This is up to you, but what you can't do is ignore the issue. If the user enters a letter when a number is expected, no value will be stored in the associated variable, so you may have an indeterminate value; this can lead to undefined behavior. One essential feature of a solution will involve checking the return value from `scanf()`. Dealing with user input in C is tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Simple Solution

Why not use two calls to `scanf()`. The first one to check whether the user enters -1; if so, the loop is terminated. Note that the value returned by `scanf()` should always be checked; in this case, the return value can be used to determine if the user has entered a number or not. If not, `a` or `b` will hold indeterminate values, which can lead to undefined behavior if used.

In this code, if the user enters -1 for the first input, or a nonnumeric value for either input, the loop is terminated. Note that the numbers in this code (and in the posted code) may be separated by an arbitrary number of whitespace characters. To accept only a single space as a delimiter would require more finesse.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a;
    int b;

    while ((scanf("%d", &a) == 1) && a != -1) {
        if (scanf("%d", &b) != 1) {
            puts("Numeric input required");
            break;
        } else {
            /* do something with a and b */
        }
    }

    puts("Program has ended");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample interactions:

```
λ> ./a.out
1 2
3 4
5 6
-1
Program has ended
λ> ./a.out
2 7
1 8
2 8
q
Program has ended
λ> ./a.out
3 1
4 1
5 a
Numeric input required
Program has ended
```

### A More Involved Solution

It takes more effort to meet the requirement that the input numbers be separated by only a single space. One way to accomplish this would be to use the `%n` directive in the second `scanf()` format string. This directive consumes no input and does not increment the assignment counter, but stores the number of characters which have been read so far in the current call to `scanf()`. Using as the second call to `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%c %n%d", &delim, &num_spaces, &b)
```

`delim` should hold the value for a space character, `num_spaces` should hold a value of 1 if only one space was present, and `b` should hold the user-input value. If `delim` is not a space, or if `num_spaces` is not 1, or if the value returned by this call to `scanf()` is not 2, then the input did not match the expected format.

In the following example, if the user enters -1 for the *first* input, the input loop is terminated. Otherwise the user input is validated. If the first input is not a number, an error message is printed and the user is prompted to enter again. If the second input is not a number, or if anything other than a single space character separates the two input values, an error message is printed and the user is prompted to enter again.

Note that when the input fails validation, at least a newline character, and possibly more characters, will remain in the input stream. To keep these extraneous characters from interfering with the next user interaction, they must be removed from the input stream. The `clear_input()` function has been added to accomplish this; it is called after a failing input to clean things up before proceeding. The `clear_input()` function is called even when the input is valid to ensure that any extra characters in the input stream are ignored.

This version accepts only numeric inputs separated by single spaces, and exits only when -1 is entered in the first position. Leading spaces *are* accepted in the input line; a technique similar to that applied to the second input could be applied to the first to enforce no leading spaces in the input format. Multiple spaces, tabs, and newlines are not accepted as delimiters between the two input numbers. This code could be further refined; note that any values after the first two input numbers are simply ignored. Instead, the code could consider such input as invalid and require strict adherence to the number-space-number line format.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clear_input(void);

int main(void) {
    int a;
    int b;

    for (;;) {
        puts("Enter two numbers separated by a single space:");
        int ret = scanf("%d", &a);
        if (ret != 1) {                      // start again for bad input
            puts("Failure in input format");
            clear_input();
            continue;
        }
        if (a == -1) {                       // exit only for -1 in first input
            break;
        }

        char delim;
        int num_spaces;
        if (scanf("%c %n%d", &delim, &num_spaces, &b) != 2
            || delim != ' '
            || num_spaces != 1) {
            puts("Failure in input format");
            clear_input();
            continue;
        } else {
            clear_input();                   // remove any extraneous characters
            /* do something with a and b */
            printf("You entered: %d, %d\n", a, b);
        }
    }

    puts("Program has ended");

    return 0;
}

void clear_input(void)
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Sample interaction:

```
λ> ./a.out
Enter two numbers separated by a single space:
1 2
You entered: 1, 2
Enter two numbers separated by a single space:
3  4
Failure in input format
Enter two numbers separated by a single space:
5   6
Failure in input format
Enter two numbers separated by a single space:
7
8
Failure in input format
Enter two numbers separated by a single space:
9 q
Failure in input format
Enter two numbers separated by a single space:
q 9
Failure in input format
Enter two numbers separated by a single space:
5 -1
You entered: 5, -1
Enter two numbers separated by a single space:
1 2 3 4
You entered: 1, 2
Enter two numbers separated by a single space:
11 12t
You entered: 11, 12
Enter two numbers separated by a single space:
11t 12
Failure in input format
Enter two numbers separated by a single space:
-1
Program has ended
```

Comment: The problem with two `scanf` is the input for `a` and `b` should only have a space between them, not a newline. I know it sounds soo stupid but that's a requirement from my professor.

Comment: This works for two inputs on the same line, i.e., input `1 2`. Note that both the posted code and the code in my answer will also work for input such as `1\n2\n`. The key point is that `\n` characters are just whitespace characters, which is what a space signifies in `scanf()` format strings.

Comment: @StannisBaratheon -- I have updated my answer with a version which satisfies the stricter requirement for a single space between input numbers. This version validates the user input more closely, and does not allow input on two lines, or tab-separated input, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put something like `x = a`, because your loop is endless.
You aren't changing value of x inside the loop.

One of the possibilities:

```
int x,a,b;
for(x=0;x!=-1;)
{
    printf("enter two numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    x = a;
}
printf("Program has ended");
```